# Как проверить AlarmManager на null?

Tags: java, android, android-alarm-manager

Дело в том, что у меня есть n-будильников. Нажимая на кнопку, я хочу удалить все ранее созданыe и пересоздать их по новому. Если ранее будильник был создан он отменяется с помощью

```
alarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 73, intent, 0));
```

но если до этого будильника не существовало, происходит краш с ошибкой невозможности применения метода на `null object`.

Как можно проверить создал ли был будильник до этого?

п.с. мне просто нужно условие для проверки отменять или не отменять будильник если он создан/не создан, но метода `alarmManager.isNull` не существует :D

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: evico.loadtime, PID: 7729
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.AlarmManager.cancel(android.app.PendingIntent)' on a null object reference
                  at evico.loadtime.Remind$11.onClick(Remind.java:446)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Мало информации что, добавьте stacktrace

Comment: Сама ссылка `alarmManager` в этом месте не инициализирована. А что бы отменить все нужно их запомнить при установке и отменять каждый по отдельности. Если их `PendingIntent'`ы отличаются только по `requestCode` - его и запишите в преференсы, например. Когда надо удалить - достали из префов, создали такой же `PendingIntent` и вызвали с ним  `cancel()`.